# It is necessary to find the index of the element that divides the array into two subsets with equal sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

For example, I have array `p=[5,3,9,8]` and element 9 have index `x=2`, and that index divide into two partitions, and these two partitions must have the same sum.

(Or they don't have to be partitioned, I don't know... )

The first partition is `5,3` the second is `8`.

```
sum([5,3]) = 8
sum([8]) = 8
```

More example...

```
p=[3,2,1,1,3,3]
output: x=3  

p=[3,17,2,1]
output: x=1
```

Random numbers coming from the user input interface. How to write in javascript code to get output that index x, which separates from two equal sums?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Keep two indices, one starting at the beginning, one at the end, as well as two sums. The increase the lower index and sum up the elements, till the sum is bigger than the other sum. Then decrease the larger index till that sum is bigger again. If the algorithm stops with both indexes being equal, you found the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use two pointers to solve it in O(n) time and constant space as follows:

```js
const findTheIndex = (arr = []) => {
  if (!arr || arr.length < 3) {
    return -1
  }

  let left = 0
  let right = arr.length - 1
  let leftSum = arr[0]
  let rightSum = arr[right]

  left += 1
  right -= 1

  while (left < right) {
    if (leftSum < rightSum) {
      leftSum += arr[left]
      left += 1
    } else {
      rightSum += arr[right]
      right -= 1
    }
  }

  if (leftSum == rightSum) {
    return left;
  }

  return -1
};

console.log(findTheIndex([2, 3, 8, 5]))
console.log(findTheIndex([3,2,1,1,3,3]))
console.log(findTheIndex([3,17,2,1]))
console.log(findTheIndex([1,2,3,4]))
```